# Sorting records based on time which is nvarchar(max) type

Tags: sql-server-2008, time

i have a nvarchar(max) field named PublishTime, which contains the time in HH:MMtt (10:20AM), now i want to sort the results based on this field, but as it is the nvarchar type, i cannot use it for order by clause, can anyone help me how can i sort results based on this field.

I tried below query which is throwing conversion error

```
select c.PublishDate, c.PublishTime from CrossArticle_Article c
inner join CrossArticle_ArticleToCategory a2c
on c.Id = a2c.ArticleId
inner join CrossArticle_Category cc
on a2c.CategoryId = cc.Id
where cc.Id = 86 order by c.PublishDate, convert(nvarchar(max), cast(c.PublishTime as time)) desc
```

Comment: Can you change the datatype of that field?

Comment: Have you tried casting the NVARCHAR(MAX) into DATETIME to then use the ORDER BY clause?

Comment: actually data for that field is coming from front end asp.net, webpage (dropdown list), so if i make it datetime, i wont be able to store the time in those fields, and also i have lacs of records which already have time, if i change the type now, will those values will retain?

Comment: yes @FrancisP i tried that, still not working

Comment: Even if you can't change to the time datatype which is the correct thing to do (never store data in a data type that is not the correct one for the type of data, you many have non-time junk data in there now), you must stop using nvarchar (max) for these types of fields. You should only use nvarchar(max) if you expect to have data that is over 8000 characters. Go Google the indexing problems of nvarchar (max).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL 2008, there is a TIME datatype which is ideal here - I'd really recommend switching the datatype of that field - use the smallest, most appropriate datatype for the data it's going hold.

Assuming all the values are valid times, here's a full example to demonstrate:

```
CREATE TABLE #Example
(
PublishTime NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

-- Insert some sample data
INSERT #Example (PublishTime) VALUES ('10:20AM'), ('10:20PM'), (NULL), ('')

-- Demonstrate the NVARCHAR -> TIME conversion
SELECT PublishTime, CAST(PublishTime AS TIME) AS ConvertedToTimeDataType
FROM #Example

-- This will change the datatype on the table
ALTER TABLE #Example
ALTER COLUMN PublishTime TIME 

-- Now check what is now in the table
SELECT * FROM #Example

DROP TABLE #Example
```

So, if you can switch the datatype, you can then do:

```
SELECT Something
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY PublishTime
```

No converting/special handling of the field required, which means if there's a suitable index in place on PublishTime, it will be able to be used.

Comment: YOu may need to check your data before you convert to make sure it is all time data. One of the problems with using the inappropriate data type is that bad data gets entered. With the time data type, non times cannot be entered. so you don't have to fix a time of 25:99 or ASAP when you use the correct data type from the start.

Comment: i did as you said, i added the column in the select query and this time it was converted to time type, holding the time which was in string format, and then ordered that field, but database engine seems to not convert that from string to time, any help

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select c.PublishDate, c.PublishTime from CrossArticle_Article c
inner join CrossArticle_ArticleToCategory a2c
on c.Id = a2c.ArticleId
inner join CrossArticle_Category cc
on a2c.CategoryId = cc.Id
where cc.Id = 86 order by cast(c.PublishTime as TIME) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a datetime field.   You have date and time in separate fields as strings, which is an antipattern to be avoided.

You can utilize `CROSS APPLY` to refer to the concatenated datetime field you make in the `order by`:

```
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST((PUBLISHDATE + ' ' +PUBLISHTIME) as datetime)) CxA(FullDate)

ORDER BY FullDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Erm What's this?

```
order by c.PublishDate, convert(nvarchar(max), cast(c.PublishTime as time)) desc
```

That's casting a string as a time and then converting to a string.

it should be

```
order by c.PublishDate, cast(c.PublishTime as time)) desc
```

or convert if it won't cast for some reason.

Like others though I'd build data and time in to one value, and then convert / cast that for ordering.

I'd also seriously look at doing something when bringing the data in, to get a date time so I could index it, unless this was a very infrequent requirement. It's going to be horribly inefficient.